# Need help to understand inductor based non-isolated offline buck converter

Tags: transformer, switch-mode-power-supply, buck, power-engineering, ferrite-bead

Here ADGJ IC is used in offline buck topology.
Can anyone share the schematic of it.
Picture taken from **sonoff** mini and **shelly1** board is attached below [image: Sonoff mini] [image: Picture taken from Shelly1]

Comment: Wikipedia: [SMPS types](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Switched-mode_power_supply#Types). Pick one of your fancy and it will give you the basic schematic. Search for that on any power IC manufacturer site and grab a product datasheet and have a schematic for that part. What kind of research have you done? Your question is very unspecific, there are a lot of different kinds and each of them has their own schematic.

Comment: @Arsenal Can you please show me the datasheet of that type of IC.

Comment: There is no single chip that covers all the SMPS cases, so it depends what kind of SMPS you are doing. What voltages are there on input and output terminals? What currents? Will it have DC or AC input? Will it have mains input? Will the output need be isolated from mains or not?

Comment: @theMastermind From Arsenal's link - see [this](https://wiki2.org/en/Boost_converter)  Boost Converter explanation. This explains a typical single inductor topology and ALL inductor based converters are based on the same principles.  In this case (and many others) an input voltage is applied across and inductor. Current increases ~= linearly with time. At some point the input voltage is removed. The inductor voltage polarity INSTANTANEOUSLY reverse and the voltage assumes the value needed to GUARANTEE that the inductor current is continuous across the switching transition. All else follows.

Comment: @RussellMcMahon  220V AC at input and 5v 200ma at output.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The circuit appears to be based on the MPS MP17x family of offline non isolated power supplies with versions rated at from 60 mA to 600 mA output.

While these ICs are useful, it must be noted that
**THE CIRCUIT IS LETHALLY DANGEROUS** at all times.
The output is not isolated from AC mains and ALL parts of  the circuit should be regarded as being at mains potential at all times.

**These devices are only suitable for applications where ALL parts of the circuit and anything powered by it is provided with mains grade insulation and isolation.**

**IF L & N inputs are swapped (as happens) then Output GND will be hard connected to Live and Vout will be at mains live less a few volts DC.**

[Here](https://www.monolithicpower.com/en/catalogsearch/result/?q=mp17) are links to a family of related datasheets.

[Here](https://www.monolithicpower.com/en/mp173.html) is the product page for the MP173 with up to 280 mA output. The circuit below from that page should be familiar.

[image]

MP173 data sheet [here](https://www.monolithicpower.com/en/documentview/productdocument/index/version/2/document_type/Datasheet/lang/en/sku/MP173/document_id/38/)

---

Cicuit provided by @TheMastermind

[image]

Answer (score 3):

After searching a Lot I found it :) thanks for every one who helped.[image]

**_______________________________________________**

Note:

THE CIRCUIT IS LETHALLY DANGEROUS at all times.
The output is not isolated from AC mains and ALL parts of the circuit should be regarded as being at mains potential at all times.

These devices are only suitable for applications where ALL parts of the circuit and anything powered by it is provided with mains grade insulation and isolation.

IF L & N inputs are swapped (as happens) then Output GND will be hard connected to Live and Vout will be at mains live less a few volts DC.

Comment: A link to where you found it would be of interest. Note that **THAT CIRCUIT IS LETHALLY DANGEROUS** . The output is not isolated from AC mains and ALL parts of  the circuit should be regarded as being at mains potential at all times. IF L & N inputs are swapped (as happens) then Output GND will be hard connected to Live and Vout will be at mains live less a few volts DC.

Comment: This answer will probably be converted to a comment in the next few days if it is not fleshed out somewhat.

Comment: That’s not a flyback. It’s a buck converter.